# I want to delete items from Firebase realtime database on button click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete the item from the Firebase real-time database by clicking the button in JavaScript. How can I delete it? I'm getting this error: app.js:61 Uncaught ReferenceError: the key is not defined in console.

I have uploaded my complete code on jsfiddle. Where is my mistake?

https://jsfiddle.net/waqasumer/z7wt6d0e/7/

```
    var main = document.getElementById("main-section");

function saveData() {
    var todoItem = document.getElementById("todo-item");

    if (todoItem.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter task");
    } else {
        var key = firebase.database().ref('tasks').push().key;
        var tasks = {
            todoItem: todoItem.value,
            key: key
        }
        firebase.database().ref('tasks/' + key).set(tasks);
        document.getElementById("todo-item").value = "";
    }

}

function getData() {
    firebase.database().ref('tasks').on('child_added', function (data) {
        var item = data.val().todoItem;
        for (var i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement("div");
            row.setAttribute("class", "row");

            var col1 = document.createElement("div");
            col1.setAttribute("class", "col text");
            var task = document.createTextNode(item);
            col1.appendChild(task);
            row.appendChild(col1);

            var col2 = document.createElement("div");
            col2.setAttribute("class", "col");

            var editBtn = document.createElement("button");
            editBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm fa fa-pencil-square-o");
            editBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "editTodo(this)");
            col2.appendChild(editBtn);
            row.appendChild(col2);

            var col3 = document.createElement("div");
            col3.setAttribute("class", "col");

            var deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
            deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm btn-danger fa fa-remove");

            deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteTodo(this)");
            col3.appendChild(deleteBtn);
            row.appendChild(col3);
            main.appendChild(row);
            break;

        }
    })
}

getData();

function deleteTodo(e) {
    firebase.database().ref('tasks').child(key).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First I think you'll want to get your data differently. Try something like this:

```
function getData() {
  tasks = [];
  firebase.database.ref('/tasks/').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      tasks.push(childData);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      const task = tasks[i];
    }
  })
}
```

Then you can access the items you saved in firebase with dot notation, like **task.todoItem** for the content of the task and **task.key** for the key value that firebase pushed.

Then one way to do what you're looking for is to populate your markup with the pushed key that corresponds to the task. You can do it similar to how you pulled the todo item but also get the key:

- var item = task.todoItem;
- var taskKey = task.key

Then populate a data attribute on the row item with the key:

- row.setAttribute("class", "row");
- row.setAttribute("data-key", "taskKey");

Then in your delete function, do the following:

```
function deleteTodo(clickedElement) {
    const key = clickedElement.parentElement.getAttribute(data-key);
    firebase.database().ref('tasks').child(key).remove();
}
```

Now "key" in your delete function should have a value.

I've edited the JS code in your snippet to incorporate my changes, see if it works:

```
var main = document.getElementById("main-section");

function saveData() {
    var todoItem = document.getElementById("todo-item");

    if (todoItem.value === "") {
        alert("Please enter task");
    } else {
        var key = firebase.database().ref('tasks').push().key;
        var tasks = {
            todoItem: todoItem.value,
            key: key
        }
        firebase.database().ref('tasks/' + key).set(tasks);
        document.getElementById("todo-item").value = "";
    }

}

function getData() {
  tasks = [];
  firebase.database.ref('/tasks/').on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      tasks.push(childData);
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      const task = tasks[i];
      var item = task.todoItem;
      var key = task.key;
      var row = document.createElement("div");
      row.setAttribute("class", "row");
      row.setAttribute("data-key", "key");

      var col1 = document.createElement("div");
      col1.setAttribute("class", "col text");
      var newTask = document.createTextNode(item);
      col1.appendChild(newTask);
      row.appendChild(col1);

      var col2 = document.createElement("div");
      col2.setAttribute("class", "col");

      var editBtn = document.createElement("button");
      editBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-success btn-circle btn-sm fa fa-pencil-square-o");
      editBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "editTodo(this)");
      col2.appendChild(editBtn);
      row.appendChild(col2);

      var col3 = document.createElement("div");
      col3.setAttribute("class", "col");

      var deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
      deleteBtn.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm btn-danger fa fa-remove");

      deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteTodo(this)");
      col3.appendChild(deleteBtn);
      row.appendChild(col3);
      main.appendChild(row);
      break;

      }
  })
}

getData();

function deleteTodo(clickedElement) {
    const key = clickedElement.parentElement.getAttribute('data-key');
    firebase.database().ref('tasks').child(key).remove();
}
```

Comment: And then to delete it from the front end add this line to to deleteTodo function: `clickElement.parentElement.remove();`

Comment: I tried your code but it's not deleting item from database. Second, I also have to display data on front-end  from database. To show the data on front-end i have to use "on" instead of "once".

Comment: I have edited my answer to use "on" instead of "once". Can you try again and let me know what error you get if any in the console?

Comment: I'm getting undefine in console and on front-end. It's not showing my tasks

Comment: I have updated your code on jsfiddle. Check link. I'm getting undefined on front-end

Comment: For some reason I still see the old code on the fiddle even though I'm trying to clear my cache.

Comment: Check again: https://jsfiddle.net/waqasumer/z7wt6d0e/14/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219708/discussion-between-ben-schnell-and-waqas-umer).

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to get you 100% there. This fiddle is really close but not quite there, but it might help: https://jsfiddle.net/z8n3hsfy/5/